# Shorewall IPv4 Forward rule on same interface

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, shorewall

I have a shorewall configuration and would like to allow traffic, coming from one interface and going out to the same interface.

The traffic is going from

```
192.168.108.2 -> 192.168.108.1 -> 192.168.108.10
```

On `192.168.108.1`, what I have is:

```
/etc/shorewall/policy:


vpn2            vpn2            ACCEPT
```

This creates me the iptables rule:

```
710 59640 vpn2_frwd  all  --  wg1    any     anywhere             anywhere
```

But I still get DROP messages in the system log:

```
[...] sfilter DROP IN=wg1 OUT=wg1 MAC= SRC=192.168.108.2 DST=192.168.108.10 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=59232 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=21 SEQ=602
```

What shorewall configuration do I need to make the traffic pass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

I just needed to add the whole subnet as AllowedIPs in Wireguard on the Wireguard clients.

```
AllowedIPs = 192.168.108.0/24
```

I had earlier just had added the single IPs, I wanted traffic to pass between.